# Enumerate counter stuck on 0

Tags: python

```
import spssaux, spss, collections
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import Counter

def create_vars():

    vdict=spssaux.VariableDict()
    varlist = ['ID','ID2', 'Var1','Var2', 'Var3', 'Var4']
    donthave=[v for v in varlist if v not in vdict]

    for i in range(len(donthave)):
        myvar=donthave[i]
        spss.Submit(r'NUMERIC %s' %(myvar))
        #spss.Submit(r'ALTER TYPE %s (ADATE10)' %(myvar))
        
    
    def repeat(lst, dt1, dt2, dt3, dt4):
        if dt1: date=dt1
        elif dt2: date=dt2
        elif dt3: date=dt3
        elif dt4: date=dt4
        else: date=None
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            lst[i].append(date)
    
    def rcnv():
    
        index=spssaux.VariableDict().VariableIndex
        v_idx=[index(v) for v in varlist]
        
        vals = [None] * len(v_idx)
        row_to_all=[]
        for i,v in enumerate(v_idx):
            row_to_all.append(i)
        
        cur=spss.Cursor(var=v_idx, accessType='w')
        #cvtDates="ALL"
        for i in range(cur.GetCaseCount()):
            row=cur.fetchone()
            for i,v in enumerate(row):
                j=row_to_all[i]
                vals[j]=v
            
              
            (ID1, ID2, Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4) = vals
            lst=[]
            lst.append([UniqueDefID.rstrip()])
            for i,v in enumerate(lst):
                print(i)
            
    rcnv()
          
create_vars()
```

I'm trying to rewrite someone's old code to incorporate new information. The `enumerate` portion looks pretty important to the rest of the code so I'm trying to figure out how to get it to work.

Whenever I try to do:

```
for i,v in enumerate(lst):
    print(i)
```

My output is:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

but expected is:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `BEGIN PROGRAM Python3.` and `END PROGRAM.` are not valid Python syntax. What exactly are you doing? Anyway, the built-in `enumerate` does what you expect it to, and not what you report seeing; so the problem must be somewhere else (e.g. something replacing the built-in `enumerate` with a different function elsewhere). So it's not possible to help you with this on the information available.

Comment: when you print, your lst is exactly 1 element long, thus the index is always 0.

Comment: We don't have enough information about what this code is supposed to do to tell what it should look like, so we can't tell you how to fix it, but Bing Wang's comment correctly explains the observed behavior.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel this is for an SPSS python function.

Comment: @BingWang but it's not?? when i print my list there are many elements.

Comment: Yes, it is. By doing `lst=[]` and then immediately `lst.append([UniqueDefID.rstrip()])`, you produce a list with one element.

Answer (score 2):

```
def create_vars():
    ...
    def rcnv():
       ...
       for i in range(cur.GetCaseCount()):                # Outer Loop
            ...
            lst=[]                                        # List creation
            lst.append([UniqueDefID.rstrip()])            # List append
            for i,v in enumerate(lst):                    # Inner Loop
                print(i)
```

You have two nested loops, In the outer, you're looping over your CaseCount, but in the loop, you're making a new list, append one element into it, and then loop over that one-element-list; hence you always get the first index there.

(As written before, you're also shadowing your outer `i` there)

Comment: when i print UniqueDefID, i get 7 distinct values though? not just one value or one of the same.

Comment: When you print UniqueDefID, you get *a single string*, the *text of which* appears to contain "7 distinct values" (i.e., sequences of digit characters separated by spaces). At a very rough guess, anyway. The code you have shown doesn't include where `UniqueDefID` comes from. At any rate, it seems like you have multiple fundamental misconceptions. It would help you to make sure you understand the concept of *type* and make sure you know how to verify the type of each value in your program, and then to do so.

Comment: @NateLeMay as you call `rstrip()` on it, i'd assume that it is a string? Anyway, you're putting it in a list (notice the square brackets in the `append` call), and then append it, so assuming your UniqueDefID is `"1, 2"`, your final `list` would be `[["1, 2"]]`. First, to "add" one list to another, you can instead call `list.extend(other_list)`. Second, you might need to `.split()` your UniqueDefID.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you have your problematic loop nested inside another loop that is already using `i` as the index counter.  So you are really referencing the top level `i`. Try changing the `i` to something else on your nested loop and it should work.

Comment: While the name reuse is definitely a terrible idea, this isn't how Python scope rules work, and changing the name won't fix the observed error.

Comment: That didn't fix it, but thanks for the tip on reuse of names.